# What is wrong with my apt-get update?

Tags: apt, updates

I am trying to install libssl-dev but when I use apt-get update it throw a bunch of erros in some links. Can someone help me? How can I fix this?
I installed ubuntu 15.04 and update it to 15.10.

```
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net wily InRelease
Hit http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease
Ign http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com raring InRelease
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net wily Release.gpg
Ign http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com raring Release.gpg
Get:1 http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free amd64 Packages     [1.433 B]
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net wily Release
Ign http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com raring Release
Get:2 http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free i386 Packages     [1.204 B]
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en
Ign http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free Translation-en_US
Ign http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free Translation-en
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net wily/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net wily/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Hit http://br.archive.ubuntu.com wily InRelease
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net wily/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net wily/main Translation-en
Hit http://br.archive.ubuntu.com wily/main Sources
Hit http://br.archive.ubuntu.com wily/restricted Sources
Hit http://br.archive.ubuntu.com wily/universe Sources
Hit http://br.archive.ubuntu.com wily/multiverse Sources
Hit http://br.archive.ubuntu.com wily/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://br.archive.ubuntu.com wily/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://br.archive.ubuntu.com wily/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://br.archive.ubuntu.com wily/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://br.archive.ubuntu.com wily/main i386 Packages
Hit http://br.archive.ubuntu.com wily/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://br.archive.ubuntu.com wily/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://br.archive.ubuntu.com wily/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://br.archive.ubuntu.com wily/main Translation-en
Hit http://br.archive.ubuntu.com wily/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://br.archive.ubuntu.com wily/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://br.archive.ubuntu.com wily/universe Translation-en
Err http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com raring/main Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 130.59.10.36 80]
Err http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 130.59.10.36 80]
Err http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com raring/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 130.59.10.36 80]
Err http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 130.59.10.36 80]
Err http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com raring/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 130.59.10.36 80]
Err http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 130.59.10.36 80]
Ign http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com raring/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com raring/main Translation-en
Ign http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted Translation-en
Fetched 2.637 B in 16s (159 B/s)
```

this is my Source list:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 15.04 _Vivid Vervet_ - Release amd64 (20150422)]/ vivid main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily main restricted
deb-src http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily universe
deb-src http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as   to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily multiverse
deb-src http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any     review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.


## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu vivid partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu vivid partner
 deb http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main restricted
 deb-src http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main restricted
```

This is my lsb_release -a

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.10
Release:    15.10
Codename:   wily
```

Comment: 13.04 has reached EOL. That's why you are getting the errors. Please upgrade to a more recent release to avoid errors

Comment: @Raphael there are also Wily PPAs there O_o

Comment: @Zacharee1 - Does it work that way?

Comment: open the Update manager> Settings > Other Software and uncheck/disable the PPA that causes 404 not found errors.

Comment: @linofex that's pretty much every PPA there, including Main

Comment: @Raphael what do you mean?

Comment: @Zacharee1 - raring wily in one list?

Comment: @Raphael idk why it's like that, but something isn't right.

Comment: what happend if you change the server? try selecting the best server. click "other" option in "Download from" and then click on "select best server"

Comment: @Zacharee1 - Same thinking here too.

Comment: Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/724780/edit) your question with the output of  `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` and `lsb_release -a`

Comment: @linofex EOL releases generally don't have working PPAs

Comment: @Raphael hmm. They say they have 15.10 upgraded from 15.04, so it makes even less sense that there are 13.04 PPAs there/

Comment: @Zacharee1 - Its confusing. No sense at all.

Comment: @linofex when I change the server nothing new happens. And I am unable to uncheck the ppa in the update manager. It just dont respond to my commands.

I don't know if there is some relation but, I can not put google chrome as my default browser neither.

Comment: After I shutdown the computer and turn it on again, everything came back to normal. -.-